# How do I set a custom Author name in TortoiseSVN locally?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, automatic-properties

I am using auto props to populate the $Id$ tag with TortoiseSVN but it is using the author name that is the name of the computer, in this case 'Peter'.

I want it to use my name instead of the computer's account name. I am using Vista on this machine. The repo is local to my machine.

Thanks!

Comment: It's the login name you use to authenticate towards `svnserve` that's used. By coincidence, are both your machine name and login to svn the same?

Comment: @goreSplatter:  Should form that comment into answer, I think you hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @jgifford25 I'm not that cheap ;-)

Comment: I think you meant [keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) with `svn:keywords`. [auto-props](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.confarea.html) is another feature, and tsvn:autoprops is yet another feature specific to TortoiseSVN. Unless you are using auto-props to automatically set the `svn:keywords` property on all your files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseSVN does not have such a feature. It only asks for a username if the server requests one. Since your repo is local, there is no authentication at all and therefore TSVN doesn't ask for a username/password.
In that case, the windows logon name is used automatically.

Sorry.